Particles (imported from embergen) keep disappearing from renders
I've imported particles (not volume) from Embergen, made them show up as points using geometry nodes (so it won't tax and according to this tutorial) but when I render, sometimes they render out nicely, but most of the times they are gone from the render. Also, sometimes, blender crashes on a random frame of the animation. Is there something wrong that I am doing? Is there another way to render particles imported from Embergen?
If i make particles as instances, it will tax super hard (because there's billion particles) and also apparently there's no motion blur.
This is my geo nodes setup: (I know, it looks weird to make it points to mesh and back to points, but that's the only way I found that it works)

These are import settings (by default)

I tried randomly hitting render until particles show up in render and it stayed so far and did not crash.
Just noticed that it says "The cycles alembic procedural is only available with the experimental feature set" although I am not using it. Should I change to experimental feature set for better results?

Screenshots would be useful (don’t photograph your monitor, please).

Hello and welcome. Do you have a question we can answer? Could you edit your post and rephrase it to read like an inquiry, so we know for sure what you need?

As it stands this post seems unclear and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

For your Edit 2: why don't you just enable Experimental, what are you afraid of? Just do it, it's your file and you can see for yourself if it helps anything instead of us guessing anything since we don't know all properties of your scene and objects.

Right now, it's rendering just fine and I don't want to stop the render. I was just wondering if someone has tried this with better results. I will need to render two more renders, and I'll try it myself after this render hopefully finishes ( in like a day)

I've got 1 render done. I've tried to enable experimental feature set, even updated nvidia driver and changed into the newest version of blender, It has randomly worked on one PC, but on my laptop it still doesn't work. when I start to render animation, first frame is OK and in the second, the particles dissapear and sometimes, blender crashes... I'm starting to suspect, it's some sort of a bug, but I would like to find a workaround

I think I found the issue. As soon as I turned OFF Persistent Data from the rendering tab, It started working
